# c++ pipe buffering disable

Tags: c++, linux, pipe

How to disable buffering in pipe. I'm creating a simple recorder/player for I/O. To do this I need record output witch time delays.

To record delays, I need something like this

```
example tekst
"wait 1s"
example tekst
"wait 1s"
example tekst
...
```

but if I use

```
pipe2(in, O_DIRECT );
```

i see something like this

```
"wait 100s"
"100 times" example tekst
"wait 100s"
"100 times" example tekst
...
```

man7 tells:

```
   O_DIRECT (since Linux 3.4)
          Create a pipe that performs I/O in "packet" mode.  Each
          write(2) to the pipe is dealt with as a separate packet, and
          read(2)s from the pipe will read one packet at a time.
```

I tried to disable buffering, by:

```
fcntl(in[1], F_SETPIPE_SZ, 1);
```

but it's still not working.

read.cpp

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <assert.h>
bool keep = true;

void intHandler(int dummy) {
    keep = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);
    int in[2];
    int out[2];
    int pid;
    int fo;
    char buf[1024];
    pipe2(in, O_DIRECT );
    pipe2(out, O_DIRECT );
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        close(in[0]);
        close(out[1]);
        close(0);
        close(1);
        dup2(in[1], 1);
        dup2(out[0], 0);
        close(in[1]);
        close(out[0]);
        sleep(1);
        char *newargv[] = {"/root/Pulpit/a1", NULL, NULL, NULL};
        char *newenviron[] = {NULL};
        int ret = execve("/root/Pulpit/a1", newargv, newenviron);
        printf("%d", ret);
        return 0;
    } else {
        close(out[0]);
        close(in[1]);
        int n = 0;
        while (keep) {
            int wyn = read(in[0], buf, 1024);
            if (wyn > 0) {
                char aa[1024];
                write(1, buf, wyn);
                fsync(1);
            }
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

a1.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    while(true){
    printf("example text\n");
    usleep(100000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, the suffix `.o` is for *object files*. That is, files that have been compiled into machine code, but *not linked into an executable program*. Please don't use that suffix for executable programs.

Comment: It would make more sense to set the pipe sizes before the fork, although why you're setting them to 1 is a mystery. They will be rounded up to the page size. I don't know why you think this will 'disable buffering'.

Comment: Did you enable stdio line buffering in a1.cpp? When output is a pipe, it's block buffered by default

Comment: What do you mean by "disabling pipe buffering"? It doesn't make any sense as pipe IS a buffer. "Buffering" doesn't make sense for pipes.

Comment: I need to have direct access to output a1. (without delay, because i want to record delays)

Comment: Understood, but that is what `O_DIRECT` does. There's nothing about that need that warrants fiddling with `F_SETPIPE_SZ`, and in any case it won't do what you think. @basin's suggestion is right on the money IMO.

Comment: if i use O_DIRECT, I still see delays. (I use linux 3.10)Firstly i try use O_DIRECT, F_SETPIPE_SZ is only my try's to solve this problem.

Comment: So fiddling with F_SETPIPE_SZ didn't work. So forget about it. As already suggested. What happened when you tried @basin's excellent suggestion?

Comment: a1 is just testing the code, I can not modify the target program

Comment: But does the target program use block-buffered `stdio`? If so, you are hosed, and if it doesn't your test is irrelevant. You could at least try it, to establish some working conditions. I fail to see the point of posting here if you're not going to attempt to profit by it.

Comment: in the target program works the same way, if I run this in the terminal works well target program is adb (shell)

Comment: So let's be clear. (1) The target program uses `stdio` to write to the pipe. (2) It uses block-mode `stdio`. (3) You know this by inspecting the source code. Please confirm 3 out of 3 here.

Comment: I checked adb use printf. Yes, 3/3, i understend. thank you

Comment: Please don't use wrong language tags. If you ask for C++ files then C is the wrong language.

Comment: So, why if i run a1 in terminall i see "unbuffered" output, but if i run this in my reader output is buffered?

Comment: Because `stdio` terminal output is line-buffered and non-terminal output is block-buffered.

Comment: Can i change this in my pipe?

Comment: You can change the buffering mode of any `stdio` `FILE *`. Hard to see why you didn't ask when it was first mentioned by @basin two hours ago.

Comment: `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0)`

Comment: I can not modify the target program, and in the reader does not work